# Creating an object based on the subclasses of two other objects

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism, class-design

My design problem is as follows.

I have two classes, each with a number of subclasses. I have a factory, which needs to create an object based on the subclass of each of these objects.

This is an authentication problem. The factory generates a rule object based on the type of person and the type of resource they wish to access. The rule has alwaysAllow, NeverAllow and timeBasedAllow subclasses. With the potential for more if a more complex access system is needed in the future.

So in future ideally a new person could be created with a new subclass, a new resource with a new subclass. The parameters on which access is determined could be changed with a new rule subclass, and the specific access of each person type and room type could be changed within the rule factory.

So far the only way I can think to do this would be to have an enumeration inside the subclasses, which defeats the point because then adding a new person or room requires a new class and a change in the enum class which seems messy.

I also am very keen to keep the data and the logic separate so I can’t just move authentication methods into the person class because this would require the person class to know how many room types there were, which is definitely not ideal.

I may be after something that isn’t realistically achievable but I can’t help the feeling that there is a nice clean solution just out of my grasp.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title makes it sound as if you are searching for multiple-inheiritance, which is not allowed in Java. Unlike in C++, a class may `extend` one and only one class. However, Java also has `interface`, which I suspect may be what you seek.

An `interface` class cannot be instantiated, and may have abstract methods. A
concrete class may `implement` as many interfaces as desired, and the concrete class must implement each abstract method the interface declares. Abstract classes may also implement interfaces, and abstract methods they do not implement must be implemented by concrete classes extending them.

I suggest extracting your authentication methods into an`interface`, perhaps called `AuthRule` or somesuch. `AuthRule` can have abstract methods with represent authenticating, without exposing the exact style used to authenticate. So, you would implement `AlwaysAllow implements AuthRule` and then the `authenticate` methods on `AlwaysAllow` would always return `true`.

The second thing, however, is that you appear to be attempting to use **inheritance** when **composition** would better suit your needs. Now instread of having a `Person` **inherit** his authentication-rule, the rule should instead be a member field inside `Person`. So, for example:

```
class Person extends User {
  AuthRule rule;
  Person(AuthRule myrule) {
    rule = myrule;
  }

  bool authenticate(...) {
    return rule.authenticate(...);
  }
}
```

If you follow a design pattern based on injecting objects into other objects to mix in the functionality you desire, your code will become far more usable and extensible. I hope this helps your problem.

Comment: My issue with this solution is that it doesn't solve the knowledge problem. With this solution the rule the person contains has to know about each of the resources the system contains in order to decide whether that user has access because the rules differ. So any additional resource being added would mean updating every one of the user subclasses. 
I think I communicated my design badly but I envisaged rules as having been created by the factory that already has knowledge of the resource and person types but it is only temporarily used for authenticating that user with that resource.